# WiX Localization - Generic Culture?

Tags: localization, wix

Does WiX not have the concept of generic cultures?

**EDIT**: specifically, is it possible to provide strings for a language separate from a country. I'd like to translate for French, German, etc. and not specify France, Canada, Germany, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While WiX does specify specific locale and region, it isn't a problem if you're going to use the same translations anyway. Basically there's no problem specifying and using `fr-FR`/`pt-PT` instead of `fr-CA`/`pt-BR`

For example, you probably use `en-US` by default but don't have any problems if your customers have their systems configured to use `en-GB` or `en-AU` locales do you?

Comment: Ultimately, this most closely matches the info I was looking for and is obvious in retrospect. Thanks Sascha! I do find it unfortunate, however, that WiX creates seperate MSIs per culture.

Answer (score 3):

You can use generic cultures, such as "en" instead of "en-us", or "de" instead of "de-de". Set this in the Culture attribute of the WixLocalization element in the .wxl file:

```
<WixLocalization Culture="de" Codepage="1252" 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
```

...and also in the call to light using the -cultures flag:

```
Light.exe -loc German.wxl -cultures:de "*.wixobj" -out myInstaller.msi
```

...or, if you're using Visual Studio, set it in the project's properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Product/@Language="0" (see ProductLanguage in the MSI SDK).

Comment: I am sorry, my question was not nearly specific enough. I am interested in specifying strings for generic languages like French (w/o specifying France or Canada, etc.). It seems like WiX may only cater to the very specific cultures/countries.

Comment: The localization strings that come with WiX specify locale/region but you can add your own that are for the neutral locale, as Nick points out. You can get the WiX localization strings from Mercurial or the sources .zip release and modify them.